# When and where should I send push notification to user in Django?

Tags: django

For example, I have a YouTubeVideo model.

When admin creates video, he passes video id to admin interface, then on the 1st save video details are loading and admin can make some changes to this details (for example, remove something in video description):

```
def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, using=None, update_fields=None):
        if self.id is None:
            video_data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(
                'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?key=somekey&part=snippet&id=%s' % self.video_id).read())
            video_info = video_data['items'][0]['snippet']
            self.title = video_info['title']
            self.description = video_info['description']

            if 'thumbnails' in video_info:
                if 'high' in video_info['thumbnails']:
                    self.thumb = video_info['thumbnails']['high']['url']

                if 'maxres' in video_info['thumbnails']:
                    self.thumb_max_res = video_info['thumbnails']['maxres']['url']
                else:
                    self.thumb_max_res = self.thumb
```

And only after this is done (after admin edits) I want to send push notifications to users.

So, the question is, how should I do it? (I mean where in my code I should do it?)

Answer (score 1):

I think you could use django signal `post_save` method. It's intended to do post processes after an object is saved. I won't recommend overriding `save` method because it's easily messed up. Django doc: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#post-save